# How do I get Hugo server sharing the port on a windows dev environment

Tags: docker, go, visual-studio-code, hugo

So I'm running windows 11 with Ubuntu as my WSL 2 for docker.

It seems to be building and the hugo server may or may not be starting as I cannot access it on port 1313 despite forwarding those ports along. No other services are running etc. I'm assuming I have to do some configration on the docker-compose but when I add dockerComposeFile it has a conniption and fails and shows me the linux / folder list.

I have the following file configurations:
**/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json**

```
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",

    "build": {
        // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
        "context": "..",
        // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
        
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile"
    },


    "forwardPorts": [1313]


}
```

**/DockerFile**

```
FROM golang:bullseye

WORKDIR /src

RUN \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        hugo

RUN curl -L https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.96.0/hugo_0.96.0_Linux-64bit.deb -o hugo.deb

RUN apt install ./hugo.deb

RUN apt-get install nodejs -y

RUN curl -sl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y \
    nodejs
```

And finally /docker-compose.yml

```
version : '3.7'

services:
  site:
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: 
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./src
        target: /src
    tmpfs: /src/tmp
  
    #command: npm run start

    command: hugo -D server --bind 0.0.0.0

    ports: 
      - 1313:1313
```

Comment: you can try other ports to see if the issue is with 1313. hugo server -p [PORT NUMBER]